# How to make image DIVs take the same hight when responsive?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm creating an image gallery and I need my thumbnail section to stay the same height as my "big" image section.  To make this clearer I recorded a short clip:  https://www.screenmailer.com/v/9gdopLeaugePvBk . As you can see, the "big" image gets slightly shorter than the thumbnail section.  I've read other posts here but none have worked for me.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 98%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.thumbnail-container {
  height: auto;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.thumbnail-wrapper {
  padding-top: 16px;
  height: auto;
}

.img-holder {
  height: auto;
  margin-bottom: 19px;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}

.main-img-wrapper {
  height: auto;
}

.main-img-holder {
  margin-top: 16px;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  padding: 0;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Image Section -->
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 card thumbnail-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-2 thumbnail-wrapper">
          <div class="col-12 img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/126x85" class="img-fluid"></div>
          <div class="col-12 img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/126x85" class="img-fluid"></div>
          <div class="col-12 img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/126x85" class="img-fluid"></div>
          <div class="col-12 img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/126x85" class="img-fluid"></div>
          <div class="col-12 img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/126x85" class="img-fluid"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-10 main-img-wrapper">
          <div class="col-lg-12 main-img-holder">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/765x500" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [flex utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/flex/) of Bootstrap. What you need is another flexbox container with `flex-direction: column` in combination with `justify-content: space-between`. A height of 100% is important too.

For your example it's necessary to wrap the items on the left column and use the following utility classes to achieve this: `d-flex flex-column justify-content-between h-100`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container mt-4">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Image Section -->
    <div class="col-lg-7 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 card thumbnail-container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-2 thumbnail-wrapper">
          <div class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-between h-100">
            <div class="img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/126x85" class="img-fluid"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/126x85" class="img-fluid"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/126x85" class="img-fluid"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/126x85" class="img-fluid"></div>
            <div class="img-holder"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/126x85" class="img-fluid"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-10 col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-10 main-img-wrapper">
          <div class="col-lg-12 main-img-holder">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/765x500" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```